# CKAN Error: Process completed but unable to post to result_url

Tags: python, pylons, datastore, ckan

I'm using CKAN 2.9.4 when I click Upload to DataStore button, I got this error

```
Error: Process completed but unable to post to result_url
```

My ckan system is already running at

http://mindset.ccgeo.info:82/

Do I need to change in my ckan.ini file need help ?

Comment: Hi guys, I've replace my datapusher to xloader here's the link --> https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-xloader